# Javascript recorder and blob issue

Tags: javascript, html

Everything is going well regarding the recording and then when you stop the recorder the file provides a link where you can upload. My question is when you hit the stop button and the code prepares the BLOB, is there a way to transfer to BLOB wav file to Wavesurfer-JS so that it can display the wave file that was just recorded this way you can edit the wav and physically see it?

I am assuming that under the section "function createDownloadLink(blob)" is where I would capture the file to send to Wavesurfer to display the Wav File in real time? Thank you.

```js
//App.JS

//webkitURL is deprecated but nevertheless
URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

var gumStream;       //stream from getUserMedia()
var rec;        //Recorder.js object
var input;        //MediaStreamAudioSourceNode we'll be recording

// shim for AudioContext when it's not avb. 
var AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
var audioContext //audio context to help us record

var recordButton = document.getElementById("recordButton");
var stopButton = document.getElementById("stopButton");
var pauseButton = document.getElementById("pauseButton");

//add events to those 2 buttons
recordButton.addEventListener("click", startRecording);
stopButton.addEventListener("click", stopRecording);
pauseButton.addEventListener("click", pauseRecording);

function startRecording() {
 console.log("recordButton clicked");

 /*
  Simple constraints object, for more advanced audio features see
  https://addpipe.com/blog/audio-constraints-getusermedia/
 */
    
    var constraints = { audio: true, video:false }

  /*
     Disable the record button until we get a success or fail from getUserMedia() 
 */

 recordButton.disabled = true;
 stopButton.disabled = false;
 pauseButton.disabled = false

 /*
     We're using the standard promise based getUserMedia() 
     https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia
 */

 navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function(stream) {
  console.log("getUserMedia() success, stream created, initializing Recorder.js ...");

  /*
   create an audio context after getUserMedia is called
   sampleRate might change after getUserMedia is called, like it does on macOS when recording through AirPods
   the sampleRate defaults to the one set in your OS for your playback device

  */
  audioContext = new AudioContext();

  //update the format 
  document.getElementById("formats").innerHTML="Format: 1 channel pcm @ "+audioContext.sampleRate/1000+"kHz"

  /*  assign to gumStream for later use  */
  gumStream = stream;
  
  /* use the stream */
  input = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);

  /* 
   Create the Recorder object and configure to record mono sound (1 channel)
   Recording 2 channels  will double the file size
  */
  rec = new Recorder(input,{numChannels:1})

  //start the recording process
  rec.record()

  console.log("Recording started");

 }).catch(function(err) {
    //enable the record button if getUserMedia() fails
     recordButton.disabled = false;
     stopButton.disabled = true;
     pauseButton.disabled = true
 });
}

function pauseRecording(){
 console.log("pauseButton clicked rec.recording=",rec.recording );
 if (rec.recording){
  //pause
  rec.stop();
  pauseButton.innerHTML="Resume";
 }else{
  //resume
  rec.record()
  pauseButton.innerHTML="Pause";

 }
}

function stopRecording() {
 console.log("stopButton clicked");

 //disable the stop button, enable the record too allow for new recordings
 stopButton.disabled = true;
 recordButton.disabled = false;
 pauseButton.disabled = true;

 //reset button just in case the recording is stopped while paused
 pauseButton.innerHTML="Pause";
 
 //tell the recorder to stop the recording
 rec.stop();

 //stop microphone access
 gumStream.getAudioTracks()[0].stop();

 //create the wav blob and pass it on to createDownloadLink
 rec.exportWAV(createDownloadLink);
}

function createDownloadLink(blob) {
 
 var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
 var au = document.createElement('audio');
 var li = document.createElement('li');
 var link = document.createElement('a');

 //name of .wav file to use during upload and download (without extendion)
 var filename = new Date().toISOString();

 //add controls to the <audio> element
 au.controls = true;
 au.src = url;

 //save to disk link
 link.href = url;
 link.download = filename+".wav"; //download forces the browser to donwload the file using the  filename
 //add the new audio element to li
 li.appendChild(au);
 
 //add the filename to the li
 li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(filename+".wav "))

 //add the save to disk link to li
 li.appendChild(link);
 
 //upload link
 var upload = document.createElement('a');
 upload.href="#";
 upload.innerHTML = "Upload to server";
 upload.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload=function(e) {
        if(this.readyState === 4) {
            console.log("Server returned: ",e.target.responseText);
        }
    };
  
 var wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
    container: '#waveform',
    waveColor: 'violet',
    progressColor: 'purple'
});
  wavesurfer.load(blob);
  
    var fd=new FormData();
    fd.append("audio_data",blob, filename);
    xhr.open("POST","upload.php",true);
    xhr.send(fd);
 })
 li.appendChild(document.createTextNode (" "))//add a space in between
 li.appendChild(upload)//add the upload link to li

 //add the li element to the ol
 recordingsList.appendChild(li);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Simple Recorder.js demo with record, stop and pause</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>Tester</h1>
  <br>
   
<div id="controls">
  <button id="recordButton">Record</button>
    <button id="pauseButton" disabled>Pause</button>
    <button id="stopButton" disabled>Stop</button>
    </div>
    <div id="formats">Format: start recording to see sample rate</div>
   <h3>Recordings</h3>
 <br>
   <ol id="recordingsList"></ol>
 <br>
 <div id="waveform"></div>
   
   
    <!-- inserting these scripts at the end to be able to use all the elements in the DOM -->
   
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs/08e7abd9/dist/recorder.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/wavesurfer.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the wavesurfer.js `load` method loads via XHR, but there is a `loadBlob` method that takes a blob or file URL.  Perhaps changing `wavesurfer.load(blob);` to `wavesurfer.loadBlob(blob);` will yield better results.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to record user input use the MediaRecorder API:

```
  var constraints = { audio: true };
  var chunks = [];

  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
    .then(function(stream) {

      var mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

      record.onclick = function() {
        mediaRecorder.start();
      }

      stop.onclick = function() {
        mediaRecorder.stop();
      }

      mediaRecorder.onstop = function(e) {
        var blob = new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : 'audio/ogg; codecs=opus' });
        chunks = [];
        var audioURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        audio.src = audioURL;
      }

      mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
        chunks.push(e.data);
      }

    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log('The following error occurred: ' + err);
    });
```